# Finding a file of specific length in directory

Tags: linux

I have twenty directories and im looking for a file with a known length somewhere in one of the directories.

Is there a Linux command to search a directory for a file by size?

What is the best method to locate this file?

Answer (score 4):

```
find somedir ... -size <sizegoes here> ...
```